# Is it a bug of NSTextView in macOS Sierra?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, nstextview, macos-sierra

Switching to the released macOS Sierra I've noticed a very strange behavior of the NSTextView object. And what really strange is that it reproduced even on a new empty project.

Just create a new project in Xcode, add Text View in Interface Builder and run the app. Just type any text so text view become having two lines. But do not hit Enter.

Now when you grab your mouse and select the beginning of the second line, the cursor will jump onto the end of the previous one! The interesting part is that when you move the cursor with keyboard everything works fine.

[image: the cursor has jumped onto the end of the previous line]

How to avoid that glitch? I'm sure that not just me is building an app on the macOS Sierra :)

Comment: Already did :) But I'm wondering if there's any workaround for 10.12.0 :)

Comment: I noticed some bugs related to the mouse event with macOS 10.12 (not only with textview). I filled in some issue in radar. You can do the same :)